# unittest.main() not working within main()

Tags: python

I am learning unittest on class and encounter a problem that unittest.main() can not run within main function:

Here is the `class AnonymousSurvey` which collects anonymous answers to a survey question.

```
import unittest

class AnonymousSurvey:
    """Collect anonymous answers to a survey question."""

    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        print(question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        self.responses.append(new_response) 

    def show_results(self):
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in self.responses: 
            print("- " + response)
```

The unittest is encapsulated in a main() function.

```
def main():

    class TestAnonymousSurvey(unittest.TestCase):
        """Test that a single response is stored properly"""

        def test_store_single_response(self):
            question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
            my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
            my_survey.store_response("English")

            self.assertIn("English", my_survey.responses)

    unittest.main()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It report ran0 tests

```
In [64]: !python survey.py                                                                                        

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

How could I get it working within a main() area?

Answer (score 3):

As [unittest's basic example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example), you would just place the `unittest.main()` into the `if __name__ == "__main__":` if statement, leaving the unittest class outside. Hence, your unittest code should become:

```
class TestAnonymousSurvey(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test that a single response is stored properly"""

    def test_store_single_response(self):
        question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
        my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
        my_survey.store_response("English")

        self.assertIn("English", my_survey.responses)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```